# Using numpy - header argument invalid

Tags: python, numpy

I am using numpy in a basic machine learning tutorial and Eclipse with PyDev is throwing the following error:

```
header='MoleculeId,PredictedProbability', comments = '')
TypeError: savetxt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'
```

I've looked up the `numpy.savetxt` function and header is included in the structure so Im not sure where the error is. FYI, if I remove the header portion altogether the file runs as required, but I really need it to label my CSV columns.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt

def main():
    #create the training & test sets, skipping the header row with [1:]
    dataset = genfromtxt(open('Data/train.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]    
    target = [x[0] for x in dataset]
    train = [x[1:] for x in dataset]
    test = genfromtxt(open('Data/test.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]

    #create and train the random forest
    #multi-core CPUs can use: rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, n_jobs=2)
    rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
    rf.fit(train, target)
    predicted_probs = [[index + 1, x[1]] for index, x in enumerate(rf.predict_proba(test))]

    savetxt('Data/submission.csv', predicted_probs, delimiter=',', fmt='%d,%f', 
            header='MoleculeId,PredictedProbability', comments = '')

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) list the header parameter as version 1.7.0 and later. Do you have an updated version?

Comment: you need to update  numpy

Comment: Numpy version? Header is there only from 1.7

Comment: That looks like the issue. Working on the update now. Thx